# Class 'Laravelista\Comments' not found

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I wanted  to implement a comment system in my website so I went on github and found [Laravelista/Comments](https://github.com/laravelista/comments)

It gave me too much problems so I deleted it by :

- Running `composer remove laravelista\Comments`
- Checking every file (using find and replace on VScode) for the term `Laravelista\Comments` and deleting it.

Now according to VSccode(my text-editor), there is no where in my app that has the term `Laravelista\Comments` yet,when I open 
http://localhost:8000/posts/new-post-3

I get the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Class 'Laravelista\Comments' not found"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php:668
```

Please help.....

Comment: Try renaming your bootstrap/cache/config.php file to something like config.php.dnu

Comment: @ImJT But there is no  ` bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: You can try clearing cache and your configs using `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @ImJT It stops at  `bootstrap/cache/` after that is gitignore,packages.php and services.php I'm on L5

Comment: Go ahead and check inside your packages.php for the package.

Comment: @ImJT Where????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192232/discussion-between-imjt-and-titox-d-boss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your models and make sure all instances of the plugin are removed.

The plugin requires you to set fields inside your model, make sure these are removed.